# Sending mail with link that will open in popup

Tags: infopath, forms-services

I want to send a hyperlink which on clicked will open in a popup window using sputility.sendemail().

Comment: You want to send a clickable link? To do that you don't even need to htmlEncode, just print it out like this: `SPUtility.SendEmail(web, false, false,"youraddress@yourhost.com","Linktest","Link to google: http://google.com")`